# Entity Framework returns null value of associated tables when using stored procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity

I am using code-first approach in EF, I have created a stored procedure to select, and when I run it, I get the value from `User` table but the FK attributes are null.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE rsm_Select
    @Id [int]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        u.*, p.*, ut.*
    FROM
        Users u
    LEFT JOIN
        UserProfiles p ON u.userProfile_Id = p.Id
    LEFT JOIN
        UserTypes ut ON u.UserType_Id = ut.Id
    WHERE
        u.Id = @Id;
END
```

I have three classes (`User, UserProfile, UserType`):

```
Public class User
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string U_UserName { set; get; }
    public string U_UserPass { set; get; }
    public string U_Accountstat { set; get; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile_Id { set; get; }
    public virtual UserType Usertype_Id { set; get; }
}

public class Admin : User
{
    //...
}

public class SuperAdmin : Admin
{
    //...
}

public Class UserType
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string TypeName { set; get; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string UFirstName { set; get; }
    public string ULastName { set; get; }
    public string UContact { set; get; }

    public virtual User U_Id { set; get; }
}
```

These are the classes I used and according to the them the tables will be created in DB.

In `User` table, `ProfileID` and `UserTypeId` are foreign keys.

**NOW**

When I try to execute the stored procedure, I will get null in `UserProfile_ID` and `UserType_ID`.

Here's how I run it:

```
void Select(int userId)
{
    using (var context = new myCodeFirstApproach())
    {
        var Result = context.Database
                            .SqlQuery<User>("EXEC rsm_Select @Id", new SqlParameter("@Id", userId))
                            .ToList();
    }
}
```

When I debug the result, I get null on `UserProfile_Id` and `UserType_Id`, but I do get values in other fields like `U_UserName`, `U_UserPass`, `U_Accountstat`.

When I run the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, it returns correct result but not in my code.

What is wrong here?

PS: all other stored procedures for Update, Delete and Create are working fine.

I try changing the stored procedure but still the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the code a little bit .what I did is that I have separate my model classes as before I have declare some functions in my **User class** and also I inherits this class in **Admin** and then admin class was inherits in **SuperAdmin**. Now I have only **User Class** which have Properties in it and these are my domain classes. and I have create a controllers ** Class SimpleUser ,Class Admin:SimpleUser, Class SuperAdmin:Admin**, and all the logic are in them.

Also I have new StoreProcedures

```
 Create Procedure rsm.ReadData 
 @Id [int] 
 AS 
 BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM Users
 WHERE Id = @Id; END;
```

As this returns me the data of selected user by matching the ID.

**NOW**

```
void Select(int userId)
{
    using (var context = new myCodeFirstApproach())
    {
        var Result = context.Database.SqlQuery<User>("ReadeData @Id", new 
        SqlParameter("@Id", userId)).ToList();
    }
}
```

And my DOMAIN CLASSES or MODEL Classes on which the Table is created are

```
Public class User
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string U_UserName { set; get; }
    public string U_UserPass { set; get; }
    public string U_Accountstat { set; get; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile_Id { set; get; }
    public virtual UserType Usertype_Id { set; get; }
}

public Class UserType
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string TypeName { set; get; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string UFirstName { set; get; }
    public string ULastName { set; get; }
    public string UContact { set; get; }

    public virtual User U_Id { set; get; }
}
```

Note: By just removing the inheritance the issue is solved
**P.S.**
This was the alternative way to solve this problem and by using this approach my code is clean and easy to handle now. Use MVC approach ;)